# Remote Neo4j web console

Tags: neo4jclient, neo4j

I am using Neo4j 2.0 server on Cent-OS  machine. This needs be accessed from a remote web-based console. In the database,the server data location points to the folder containing the data.
When I start the database and try to access it from a remote machine, the data doesn't show up.
What could be the reason for this ??

I modeled the database on a windows machine and then take this data to remote unix machine and point that server to this folder(which is created on windows, but on UNIX based system).Is it appropriate to do? Does linux identifies the data files created on windows.

Comment: how did you install neo4j on centos? which config files did you change and how? does it work locally on the server to access neo4j and your data?

Comment: Hi Michael, I just downloaded Neo4j and did start it . I changed couple of things  1) The data location property 2) Security settings to let the remote browsers access the DB.  Now the problem is when I open the browser in Windows machine ,it doesn't show the data in the browser, though it points to the appropriate location.  3) Even when I open the local shell and run a CYPHER query, the data doesn't show up.

Comment: are you sure you've copied the graph.db directory recursively from your windows machine to the correct location? The behaviour you've described looks like the windows datastore is not at the right location.

Comment: In windows, it asks us to choose a custom directory to put the data in.I took the same directory and put in the linux machine. And in the server configuration , I pointed the data location to this new directory in linux box.

Comment: Can you show the exact 1) location + directory contents, 2) your neo4j-server.properties